# MultiversX bulding smart contract with mxpy error [E0554]

Tags: rust, multiversx

a bit new in MultiversX building.
Using WSL2 on Windows, and rustc version is:
`:~/multiversx/smart_contracts/crowdfunding$ rustc -V  rustc 1.70.0 (90c541806 2023-05-31)`

All this tools are new for me. I am following the Crowdfunding tutorial (https://docs.multiversx.com/developers/tutorials/crowdfunding-p1/). When it comes to build the contract, I get the issue:

```
~/multiversx/smart_contracts/crowdfunding$ mxpy contract build
INFO:projects.core:build_project.directory: /home/dev/multiversx/smart_contracts/crowdfunding
INFO:projects.core:build_project.debug: False
INFO:modules:install: key=rust, tag=nightly, overwrite=False
INFO:myprocess:run_process: ['rustc', '--version'], in folder: None
INFO:myprocess:Successful run. Output:
rustc 1.72.0-nightly (839e9a6e1 2023-07-02)

INFO:modules:Already exists. Skip install.
INFO:ProjectRust:wasm-opt is installed.
    Updating crates.io index
   Compiling proc-macro2 v1.0.63====>  ]  93.33%, (68/75) resolving deltas
   Compiling autocfg v1.1.0
   Compiling quote v1.0.29
   Compiling unicode-ident v1.0.9
   Compiling memchr v2.5.0
   Compiling once_cell v1.18.0
   Compiling cfg-if v1.0.0
   Compiling rustix v0.38.2
   Compiling syn v1.0.109                ] 0/109: proc-macro2(build.rs), once_cell, quote(build.rs), unicode-ident, memchr(build.rs), rustix(build.rs), autocfg, cfg-if
   Compiling version_check v0.9.4        ] 1/109: proc-macro2(build.rs), once_cell, quote(build.rs), unicode-ident, memchr(build.rs), syn(build.rs), rustix(build.rs), autocfg
   Compiling linux-raw-sys v0.4.3        ] 2/109: proc-macro2(build.rs), once_cell, quote(build.rs), memchr(build.rs), syn(build.rs), version_check, rustix(build.rs), autocfg
   Compiling num-traits v0.2.15          ] 3/109: proc-macro2(build.rs), quote(build.rs), memchr(build.rs), syn(build.rs), version_check, linux-raw-sys, rustix(build.rs), autocfg
   Compiling num-integer v0.1.45         ] 4/109: proc-macro2(build.rs), num-traits(build.rs), quote(build.rs), memchr(build.rs), syn(build.rs), version_check, linux-raw-sys, rustix(build.rs)
   Compiling bitflags v2.3.3             ] 5/109: proc-macro2(build.rs), num-traits(build.rs), quote(build.rs), memchr(build.rs), syn(build.rs), num-integer(build.rs), linux-raw-sys, rustix(build.rs)
   Compiling ahash v0.8.3                ] 6/109: proc-macro2(build.rs), num-traits(build.rs), quote(build.rs), bitflags, memchr(build.rs), syn(build.rs), num-integer(build.rs), rustix(build.rs)
   Compiling num-bigint v0.4.3          ] 14/109: num-traits(build.rs), num-integer(build), ahash(build.rs), memchr, proc-macro2(build), rustix(build), quote(build), syn(build)
   Compiling smallvec v1.10.0           ] 15/109: num-traits(build.rs), ahash(build.rs), memchr, proc-macro2(build), num-bigint(build.rs), rustix(build), quote(build), syn(build)
   Compiling utf8parse v0.2.1           ] 18/109: proc-macro2, num-traits(build), memchr, num-bigint(build.rs), smallvec, rustix(build), quote(build), syn(build)
   Compiling hex v0.4.3                 ] 19/109: proc-macro2, num-traits(build), utf8parse, memchr, num-bigint(build.rs), smallvec, rustix(build), syn(build)
   Compiling regex-syntax v0.7.2        ] 21/109: proc-macro2, hex, num-traits(build), utf8parse, memchr, num-bigint(build.rs), smallvec, rustix
   Compiling libc v0.2.147              ] 22/109: proc-macro2, hex, regex-syntax, num-traits(build), memchr, num-bigint(build.rs), smallvec, rustix
   Compiling nibble_vec v0.1.0          ] 24/109: proc-macro2, libc(build.rs), num-traits, hex, regex-syntax, memchr, num-bigint(build.rs), rustix
   Compiling anstyle-parse v0.2.1       ] 25/109: proc-macro2, libc(build.rs), num-traits, regex-syntax, memchr, num-bigint(build.rs), nibble_vec, rustix
   Compiling anstyle v1.0.1             ] 29/109: proc-macro2, libc(build.rs), num-traits, ahash(build), regex-syntax, quote, memchr, rustix
   Compiling syn v2.0.23                ] 30/109: proc-macro2, libc(build.rs), num-traits, regex-syntax, quote, anstyle, memchr, rustix
   Compiling aho-corasick v1.0.2        ] 31/109: proc-macro2, num-traits, regex-syntax, quote, syn, anstyle, memchr, rustix
   Compiling is-terminal v0.4.8         ] 33/109: proc-macro2, num-traits, regex-syntax, syn, syn, memchr, aho-corasick, rustix
   Compiling colorchoice v1.0.0         ] 35/109: num-traits, regex-syntax, syn, syn, memchr, aho-corasick, libc(build), rustix
   Compiling endian-type v0.1.2         ] 36/109: num-traits, regex-syntax, syn, syn, aho-corasick, libc(build), colorchoice, rustix
   Compiling anstyle-query v1.0.0       ] 37/109: num-traits, regex-syntax, syn, syn, aho-corasick, libc(build), endian-type, rustix
   Compiling lazy_static v1.4.0         ] 39/109: num-integer, num-traits, regex-syntax, syn, syn, aho-corasick, endian-type, rustix
   Compiling serde v1.0.165             ] 40/109: num-integer, lazy_static, num-traits, regex-syntax, syn, syn, aho-corasick, rustix
   Compiling radix_trie v0.2.1          ] 41/109: num-integer, num-traits, regex-syntax, syn, syn, serde(build.rs), aho-corasick, rustix
   Compiling anstream v0.3.2            ] 42/109: num-integer, num-traits, regex-syntax, syn, syn, serde(build.rs), aho-corasick, radix_trie
   Compiling aho-corasick v0.7.20       ] 46/109: serde(build), anstream, regex-syntax, syn, syn, libc, aho-corasick, num-bigint
   Compiling bstr v1.5.0>               ] 47/109: anstream, regex-syntax, syn, syn, aho-corasick, libc, aho-corasick, num-bigint
   Compiling regex v1.8.4               ] 48/109: regex-syntax, syn, syn, bstr, aho-corasick, libc, aho-corasick, num-bigint
   Compiling indexmap v1.9.3            ] 50/109: regex, ahash, regex-syntax, syn, syn, libc, aho-corasick, num-bigint
   Compiling same-file v1.0.6           ] 51/109: regex, ahash, regex-syntax, syn, syn, indexmap(build.rs), aho-corasick, num-bigint
   Compiling log v0.4.19=>              ] 52/109: regex, regex-syntax, syn, syn, indexmap(build.rs), aho-corasick, same-file, num-bigint
   Compiling anyhow v1.0.71             ] 53/109: regex, regex-syntax, syn, syn, log, indexmap(build.rs), aho-corasick, num-bigint
   Compiling semver v1.0.17             ] 54/109: regex, regex-syntax, syn, syn, log, indexmap(build.rs), anyhow(build.rs), aho-corasick
   Compiling clap_lex v0.5.0            ] 55/109: regex, regex-syntax, syn, syn, indexmap(build.rs), anyhow(build.rs), aho-corasick, semver(build.rs)
   Compiling heck v0.4.1==>             ] 56/109: regex, regex-syntax, syn, syn, anyhow(build.rs), aho-corasick, semver(build.rs), clap_lex
   Compiling arrayvec v0.7.4            ] 57/109: regex, regex-syntax, syn, syn, anyhow(build.rs), semver(build.rs), clap_lex, heck
   Compiling fnv v1.0.7===>             ] 58/109: regex, arrayvec, regex-syntax, syn, syn, anyhow(build.rs), semver(build.rs), heck
   Compiling strsim v0.10.0>            ] 59/109: regex, arrayvec, regex-syntax, syn, syn, anyhow(build.rs), semver(build.rs), fnv
   Compiling globset v0.4.10            ] 61/109: regex, arrayvec, regex-syntax, syn, syn, strsim, semver(build.rs), anyhow(build)
   Compiling clap_builder v4.3.10       ] 62/109: regex, arrayvec, regex-syntax, syn, syn, strsim, semver(build.rs), globset
   Compiling walkdir v2.3.3=>           ] 65/109: regex, regex-syntax, syn, syn, strsim, indexmap(build), globset, clap_builder
   Compiling hashbrown v0.13.2          ] 66/109: regex, regex-syntax, syn, syn, walkdir, strsim, globset, clap_builder
   Compiling atty v0.2.14===>           ] 67/109: regex, syn, syn, walkdir, hashbrown, strsim, globset, clap_builder
   Compiling thread_local v1.1.7        ] 68/109: regex, atty, syn, syn, walkdir, hashbrown, globset, clap_builder
   Compiling hex-literal v0.3.4         ] 69/109: regex, thread_local, syn, syn, walkdir, hashbrown, globset, clap_builder
   Compiling serde_json v1.0.99         ] 70/109: regex, syn, syn, walkdir, hashbrown, hex-literal, globset, clap_builder
   Compiling hashbrown v0.12.3          ] 71/109: regex, syn, syn, serde_json(build.rs), hashbrown, hex-literal, globset, clap_builder
   Compiling bitflags v1.3.2==>         ] 72/109: regex, syn, syn, serde_json(build.rs), hex-literal, hashbrown, globset, clap_builder
   Compiling ignore v0.4.20===>         ] 74/109: regex, serde_json(build), syn, syn, hex-literal, hashbrown, globset, clap_builder
   Compiling colored v2.0.1====>        ] 76/109: regex, ignore, indexmap, syn, syn, hex-literal, globset, clap_builder
   Compiling Inflector v0.11.4=>        ] 79/109: regex, ignore, colored, syn, syn, semver, anyhow, clap_builder
   Compiling unicode-segmentation v1.10.1 80/109: regex, ignore, syn, syn, semver, Inflector, anyhow, clap_builder
   Compiling ryu v1.0.13========>       ] 81/109: regex, ignore, unicode-segmentation, syn, syn, Inflector, anyhow, clap_builder
   Compiling itoa v1.0.7========>       ] 82/109: ignore, unicode-segmentation, syn, syn, ryu, Inflector, anyhow, clap_builder
   Compiling rustc_version v0.4.0       ] 83/109: ignore, unicode-segmentation, syn, syn, ryu, Inflector, itoa, clap_builder
   Compiling common-path v1.0.0==>      ] 84/109: ignore, rustc_version, unicode-segmentation, syn, syn, Inflector, itoa, clap_builder
   Compiling pathdiff v0.2.1=====>      ] 85/109: ignore, rustc_version, unicode-segmentation, syn, syn, itoa, common-path, clap_builder
   Compiling convert_case v0.6.0=>      ] 88/109: ignore, rustc_version, unicode-segmentation, syn, syn, clap_builder
   Compiling serde_derive v1.0.165>     ] 91/109: ignore, syn, syn, clap_builder
   Compiling clap_derive v4.3.2===>     ] 92/109: ignore, syn, serde_derive, clap_builder
   Compiling multiversx-sc-codec-derive v0.17.29: clap_derive, syn, serde_derive, clap_builder
   Compiling multiversx-sc-derive v0.41.3 94/109: clap_derive, multiversx-sc-codec-derive, serde_derive, clap_builder
error[E0554]: `#![feature]` may not be used on the stable release channel-sc-codec-derive, multiversx-sc-derive, serde_derive
 --> /home/dev/multiversx-sdk/vendor-rust/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/multiversx-sc-derive-0.41.3/src/lib.rs:4:12
  |
4 | #![feature(proc_macro_quote)]
  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0554`.
error: could not compile `multiversx-sc-derive` due to previous error
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
CRITICAL:cli:Build error: None.=====>   ] 98/109: clap_derive
╭─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│ Build error: None.
```

As it says

```
:~/multiversx/smart_contracts/crowdfunding$ rustc --explain E0554

Feature attributes are only allowed on the nightly release channel. Stable or
beta compilers will not comply.

Erroneous code example:

``
#![feature(lang_items)] // error: `#![feature]` may not be used on the
                        //        stable release channel
``

If you need the feature, make sure to use a nightly release of the compiler
(but be warned that the feature may be removed or altered in the future).
```

I tried to install the nightly version according to https://github.com/casbin/casbin-rs/issues/215
`rustup install nightly`

Do you have any idea to help me?
Thanks a lot

--[EDIT] For those who have the same issue:
Try `mxpy contract build --no-wasm-opt` Instead of `mxpy contract build`
Thanks bluedragon1120 from https://github.com/multiversx/mx-ping-pong-sc/issues/5

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the rust installation used by your mxpy is somehow on stable release channel instead of nightly.
In order to change it to a nightly release you have to download the desired nightly release like so:

```
rustup toolchain install nightly-2023-04-24 --force
```

Then switch the installation to the downloaded release:

```
rustup default nightly-2023-04-24
```

Please make sure that you are changing the **rust installation used by mxpy**, because one might have another installation besides the one installed and used by mxpy, so if you're switching your "global" installation, mxpy will not see it.

A note here would be that by default, mxpy uses the rust installation located in `${HOME}/multiversx-sdk/vendor-rust`.

To make sure that the effects of your changes go to the correct installation, you can always try `mxpy deps check rust` to see what's mxpy using.